# Voltage across points when going in reverse direction across cell

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electrical-resistance

> When charging a rechargeable cell, an external power source pushes a current from the (+) to the (-) terminal of the cell. Consider a cell of emf $3$ V and internal resistance $0.80 \Omega$ that's being charged with a current $2.0$ A. Find the potential difference across the cell in the charging process.

Hello, I am having trouble solving the above problem.

My thought is this:

Since current is flowing from the (+) to (-) terminal, we *subtract* the voltage. Now, across the resistor, we also subtract, so $$V = -3 - 0.8 \cdot 2$$
$$V = -4.6 $$

So, I hope it means that $$V_{P}-V_{Q} = -4.6 \text{ V}$$ where $P$ is the positive terminal of the battery, and $Q$ is the negative terminal.

However, I am given the answer $V_{PQ} = V_{P} - V_Q = +4.6 \text{ V}$. Which is correct and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just chose a different sign convention to express your answer.

You used the convention, "Since current is flowing from the (+) to (-) terminal, we subtract the voltage."

Your book used the convention that the voltage is taken positive at the terminal where current is entering the device.

It is not uncommon that different conventions are used to describe the potential across a device in different situations, at least in casual speech, even when talking about the exact same device.

But in this case I think the convention you chose is not one that would be used by very many people.

If someone asked you, "what's the voltage of that cell?" you'd say it's 3 V, not -3 V. And the voltage when charging is exactly the same as when discharging, so why change the convention and suddenly call this voltage -3 V?

Or, if you consider other devices that absorb power, like resistors. If someone asks you "what's the voltage across a 100 ohm resistor with 10 mA flowing through it?", the usual answer is 1 V, not -1 V. Even though current is flowing from the positive to the negative terminal, we take the voltage to be positive. When applying KVL we might subtract this value in our equation, but when we consider it outside the context of writing KVL equations, we still express it as a positive voltage.

> So, I hope it means that $$V_{P}-V_{Q} = -4.6 \text{ V}$$ where $P$ is the positive terminal of the battery, and $Q$ is the negative terminal.

In this part you have got mixed up. In order to charge a rechargeable cell, we must apply a positive voltage between the positive terminal and the negative terminal. If you did the opposite, you would only further discharge the cell (and possibly start a fire).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, technically speaking, which is correct: $$V_{PQ} = \pm 4.6 \text{ V}$$

Comment: @MangoPizza by the convention that $V_{PQ}=V_P - V_Q$, the answer is +4.6 V, since the positive terminal is at a higher potential than the negative terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity is in the problem statement,

*Find the potential difference across the cell in the charging process.*

It is often the case that the word *magnitude* is omitted and so the answer to the problem

*Find **the magnitude of** the potential difference across the cell in the charging process.*

is $4.6\,\rm V$.

Your original statement states,

*Consider a cell of emf 3 V . . . .*,

and the implication/assumption made is that when there are no external connections to the cell terminal, ie no current is passing through the cell, the potential of the terminal labelled positive/$+$/red is higher than the potential of the terminal labelled negative/$-$/black by $3\,\rm V$.

That is to say that the potential of the positive terminal is stated relative to the negative terminal and so without any other information that is the convention it is best to use when stating an answer to the problem.

So I assume that without further qualification the answer to the problem is $+4.6\,\rm V,\, (=V_{\rm P} - V_{\rm Q})$.

Here is an annotated circuit diagram with nodes $a,\,b$ and $c$.
Node $c$ is the reference node at a potential of $0\,\rm V$.

[image]

The convention used in terms of the voltages shown alongside the circuit elements is that number is the potential of the node labelled $+$ relative to the node labelled $-$.

Thus node $b$ is higher in potential than node $a$ by $1.6\,\rm V$.